# Import new products in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I can`t seem to find a way how to import new products in OpenERP.
Does OpenERP support importing new non-referenced products into it.

Most of the guides show how to export products, which they contain referecing ID`s so they can be imported back to OpenERP.

Answer (score 0):

To import product or any other data in OpenERP you need to install module named `base_import` after that you will see import link near by create button.

you can import non-reference products as well, just need to assign unique value to each because OpenERP looks for external ids. So just add one column in starting and give values anything like ext_product_1 and then carry to all next.